# AsNoTracking duplicating entities

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

sorry for my poor english - I'm using EF 5 (Code First) in an WPF (.net 4.5) application. Each window has its own context.

I have a model like this (code omitted for brevity):

```
public class Car
{
  public string Model { get; set; }  
  public int BrandId { get; set; }  
  public virtual Brand Brand { get; set; }
}
```

I use comboboxes to allow the user to associate a `Brand` to a `Car`. The problem is, every time I save a `Car`, a new, duplicated `Brand` are saved too. This happens because I load the combobox with `AsNoTracking()`.

Now, I load the combobox with `AsNoTracking()` because I was having trouble loading changes on the `Brand` table made in other DbContext instances (using `myContext.Set<Brand>().Load()`).

So my question is, how to resolve this? If there is another way to force reload of a collection (without using `AsNoTracking`), it would be nice. Even nicer would be to be able to inform EF that the `AsNoTracking` loaded entities are not new.

**EDIT 1:**
@Mark:
Thanks, attaching the entity to the context did the trick. But I use a generic base class that does the validation and save the data for all my forms so manually attaching the entities are not very practical... based on your suggestion I ended up doing this, after adding the Car entity and before saving it:

```
var entities = (((IObjectContextAdapter)ctx).ObjectContext.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries(EntityState.Added));

foreach (var item in entities)
{
    if ((item.Entity as EntityBase).Id > 0)
    {
        item.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(item.Entity, EntityState.Unchanged);
    }
}
```

(all my entites inherit from EntityBase and all my keys are database-generated). This worked fine but i would like a second opinion... is this good or there is an easier way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's happening is that your context isn't aware of the Brand that's attached to the Car, so it's creating a new one to match your foreign key.  You should attach the brand to the context before saving:

```
context.Brands.Attach(brand);
```

You can reload the individual Brand prior to saving by reloading it individually:

```
db.Entry(brand).Reload();
```

If you're not wanting to actually persist **any** changes to Brand when you're saving a Car, you can tell the context that the Brand has not been changed, and prevent updates.

```
context.Entry(brand).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
```

Comment: thanks, that gave me the right direction... can you give me your opinion on my edit 1 please :) ?

Comment: If I understand your logic, you're wanting to be sure no existing entity is being changed with your add?  If so, that works

Comment: Yes, I would never want to change the entities that I load with AsNoTracking() (I only use them on comboboxes). Feels a little strange but this worked fine so I guess this is it :) - thanks again.